# Serializer Nested relationships not working as it sholuld be

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

**Nested relationships** **django 1.11**

serializer:

```
class PostDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = post_detail_url
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = SerializerMethodField()
    html = SerializerMethodField()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    category = CategorySerializer()
    source = SourceSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'title',
            'image',
            'slug',
            'content',
            'source',
            'source_link',
            'category',
            'tags',
            'html',
            'publish',
            'timestamp',
            'user',
        ]
```

Response:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 3,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/posts/new-postas/",
    "title": "New Postaas",
    "image": null,
    "slug": "new-postas",
    "content": "asssaasssasa",
    "source": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "prothom alo",
    "slug": "prothom-alo"
    },
    "source_link": "http://prothom-alo.com/",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/posts/category/news/",
        "name": "news"
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "tech",
            "slug": "tech"
        }
    ],
    "html": "<p>asssaasssasa</p>\n",
    "publish": "2017-08-31",
    "timestamp": "2017-08-31T12:28:28.686538Z",
    "user": {
        "id": "ac32460f-fb7e-4755-9f7e-7c13085ee92b",
        "email": "hello@ihemel.net",
        "first_name": "Hasibul Amin",
        "last_name": "Hemel"
    }
}
```

This is fine nested relation retrieving the data.

But again in my category details api serializer below:

```
class CategoryDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = category_detail_url
    posts = PostDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'name',
            'posts'
        ]
```

Here my post serializer does not output any data in the api. I don't know. there no bug or error, just the value is not coming.

The category details api response:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 2,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/posts/category/news/",
    "name": "news"
}
```

[image: Here the Image]

Is there any solution? i searched but not found any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using fieldname `posts` in `CategoryDetailSerializer` you need to set `related_name=posts` to category relation inside `Post` model:

```
class Post(Model):
    category = ForeignKey(Category, related_name='posts')
```

Or you can use default relation name `post_set` in `CategoryDetailSerializer`:

```
class CategoryDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = category_detail_url
    post_set = PostDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
        'id',
        'url',
        'name',
        'post_set'
        ]
```

See details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations).

Also you can try to specify source on the serializer field using related_name from model:

```
posts = PostDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='cat_posts')
```

Comment: Hello,
I put this on the model..
`category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='cat_posts', default=1)


    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, related_name='rel_posts', help_text="Select tags for this review")`

for category and tags. should i change the category `related_name` to `posts`? but why? should not other than `posts` will not work?

I just not getting it. can you please describe about it? Thank you.

Comment: @Hemel from the docs: `You'll normally want to ensure that you've set an appropriate related_name argument on the relationship, that you can use as the field name.` So if you have related name you need also use this name in serializer. Or you can try to set source on `posts` field: `posts = PostDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='cat_posts')`.

Comment: And how does `post_set` will work not `posts`? if in your given example model `related_name` is `posts`?

Comment: `posts_set` will worl only if you are not using related_name. So in your case it is not the solution. Try `source` argument and if this is not work, rename field in serializer to `cat_posts`.

Comment: Ok thank you for time. Let me check it. i will get back asap. :)

Comment: I just change `posts` to `cat_posts`in `CategoryDetailSerializer` , and its working. my bad that i could not get it :) Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the CategoryDetailSerializer() not get called,
What's get called is the other Category serializer who is the CategorySerializer().

Comment: I check double from the url that it getting called.


`url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),`


and the view code.



`class CategoryDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]`

@theShakelProgrammer